# powershell - check if folder exists before deleting it

Tags: powershell

I wanna delete all folders from out of a list (list.txt). Before deleting them, I want to check if they are still existing.

How can I do this task?  Maybe with foreach or if?  I am a newbie :)

And a second task: I have this list and I want to check for the folders which are still existent and write them into a new file.

```
$homedirectory = get-content -Path "c:\SCO_scripts\homedirectory_delete\list.txt"

 if ( Test-Path -Path $homedirectory -PathType Container ) { 


Remove-item $homedirectory -Force -recurse  

}
```

or something like that?....

```
 $homedirectory = get-content -Path "c:\SCO_scripts\homedirectory_delete\list.txt"

foreach ($folder in $homedirectory)
{

exists -Path $folder      <---???  no idea how to make it :(

Add-Content -Path C:\SCO_scripts\homedirectory_delete\newFile.txt -Value $folder

}
```

Comment: If you remove those folders from your list, they should'n be existing anymore, so what do you want to achieve with your second code after the first one deleted them all?

Comment: I don't get it either.
Do you want to delete the folders or list them?

Comment: Are we talking about two different folders and two different questions?

Answer (score 0):

**would you test this please **

```
   $folders= Get-Content -Path C:\Temp\test.txt
 foreach($i in $folders){

    if (Test-Path -Path $i){
        Write-Host $i exist    
         }
    else{
        Write-Host $i not exist
}
}
```

Comment: that does not work. It marks every path as not exists. Also existing paths.  :/

Comment: @rolfderwolf Can you show your txt file ?

Comment: It looks like the second write-host should have been inside brackets.

Comment: \\domain.bla\Homeshares\Sinatra
\\domain.bla\User\Homeshares\Columbo
\\domain.bla\user\Homeshares\Coolman
\\domain.bla\user\Homeshares\Jackson
\\domain.bla\user\Homeshares\Bezos
\\domain.bla\user\Homeshares\Trump
\\domain.bla\user\Homeshares\Smith

Comment: @rolfderwolf i have update the code can you try.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

```
    $folders= Get-Content -Path c:\SCO_scripts\homedirectory_delete\list.txt


foreach ($folder in $folders) {

        $testpath  = Test-Path $folder
        
    if ($testpath -eq $true) 
    {
    Write-Host "$folder Folder Exists" -ForegroundColor Green 
    Add-Content -Path C:\SCO_scripts\homedirectory_delete\newFile.txt -Value $folder
    }

    else 
    { 
    Write-Host "$folder is not Online" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't delete any folder from the list; it only checks an writes the folder names to a text file.. why does this then answer your question?